# How do I stop the call to this function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

#### Issue:

I am calling a function on scroll in my code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function (){
    loading();
});
```

Here loading() is sending an Ajax request to load the pages, now I want to stop the call to this function when my total_pages count is equal to current_page or else it is sends too many Ajax requests.

#### Question:

How do I stop the call to this function in Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method to remove the `scroll` handler from `window`. Try:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

It should do the trick

Comment: I tried this. It is stopping the ajax requests permanently for the menu link.

What I want is scroll should get disable till the time I m not clicking the menu link again. If I click the link again Ajax requests should be made all over again till total_Page count not equals to current page.

Comment: Wasn't that what you wanted? Maybe you can change the `loading()` function and fire the ajax call only if total_pages count is not equal to current_page

Comment: I do not have access to total_pages count on static js file, for that I am calling refresh(), when this count gets equal.

Comment: Then, if I understood correctly, you can bind the scroll handler (`$(window).bind('scroll',function (){ loading(); });`) again when you click the link.

Comment: I am trying to bind the scroll on the click of a link, but some how it is not binding again  
    $('#gallery').bind("click",function()
    {$(window).bind('scroll');});

Comment: You need to add the loading function to the binding: `$("#gallery").click(function(){$(window).bind('scroll', function(){loading();});});`

Comment: @DeeptiThakur You can accept the answer if it was useful by clicking the check icon next to it :)